# How to spring url in complex application

Tags: spring, url

I'm busy with a complex webapplication with Spring Boot.
I have multiple entities that are coupled to each other.

Example:
I have the following entities: Project, Cluster, Case, Result
A Project can have multiple Clusters, but a Cluster can only belong to one Project.
A Cluster can have multiple Cases, but a Case can only belong to one Cluster.
The same with Case->Result.

The relationships are unidirectional. So a Project knows which Cluster belongs to it, But a Cluster doesn't have a clue to which Project it belongs. Same goes with Cluster->Case and Case->Result.

I have the following url structure,

```
/projects
/projects/(id project)/clusters
/projects/(id project)/clusters/(id cluster)
/projects/(id project)/clusters/(id cluster)/case
```

etc....

The problem I'm facing is when I'm at the 4th url, with the case I don't need the id of the project, because the case uses the ID of the cluster to save it.
But because of the structure of the url I need the id of the project to maintain integrity. 
And because of the nature of my relationships (unidirectional) I have to look for the id of the project in my case controller with the help of my cluster.

Is there an easy way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest another way of building of API. While defining URIs you should consider each entity as an independent object.

For example, you can have following URIs:

```
/projects GET - returns a list of projects
/projects/{id} GET - returns a details of a particular entity
/projects POST - create new project
/projects/{id} DELETE - delete project
```

In case of API for clusters you can have the same structure:

```
/clusters GET - returns a list of projects
/clusters/{id} GET - returns a details of a particular entity
/clusters POST - create new project
/clusters/{id} DELETE - delete project
```

The question is how we can create a cluster for a particular project? Easily! We can pass `projectId` in JSON body.
It's a common practice that has one big advantage - you won't have long URIs in your application.